# Is it possible to synchronize localnet SharePoint with SharePoint within Office 365 cloud?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365

Precondition: Existing Office 365 cloud product ([Office 365 Enterprise E3](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-enterprise-e3-business-software)) with SharePoint in use.

Issue: When Internet connection goes down there is no access to stored files on the SharePoint server.

Need: Be independent from stable Internet connection. Be able to work "offline" (without Internet access but with working Intranet access). Incoming paperwork have to be digitized immediately into document management system (SharePoint).

Side benefit: Internet connection is lesser used. More bandwidth for other traffic.

Desired Story: Clients inside the office (localnet) are working directly on the (localnet) SharePoint server. Clients outside the office (Internet) are working with the Office 365 cloud SharePoint server. The two SharePoint instances synchronize themselves whenever possible.

Is this desired story possible? Is SharePoint able to have a complete separated slave/mirror instance which can be operate autonomously? Do the instances synchronize each other automatically when the connection between the both instances is reestablished again?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replicate or synchronize between SharePoint out-of-the-box regardless which version or if OnPrem or in Office365.

There are 3rd party products which give you exact what you are asking for. I know two tools (alphabetically ordered):

- [DocAve Replicator](https://www.avepoint.com/products/sharepoint-infrastructure-management/sharepoint-replication/)
- [Metalogix Replicator](https://www.metalogix.com/product/replicator)

Please consult those vendors if they fit your needs.